# SOLR search is not working with @ symbol

Tags: java, solr

When we try to search Solr with **@** in the term it does not return any result.

Suppose in there is an entry with text abc@ac.in.

```
When I search abc@ac.in it works.
When I search abc@ it works.
When I search abc@a it FAILS and returns no result.
```

Can anyone please suggest?

Comment: show your schema.xml for this field.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, for this field, you're using `solr.StandardTokenizerFactory`, which is splitting text into tokens by different symbols, and one of them is `@`, so if you put `abc@ac.in` you will get something like `abc` `ac` `in` as a tokens.

For emails, I would recommend to use `solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory`, which is [saving tokens as it is](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/tokenizers.html#Tokenizers-KeywordTokenizer). It could be fine, if your field contains just email address.

But, if your field is a text field, where you want to preserve emails - you should use `solr.ClassicTokenizerFactory`, which [recognizes email addresses and domain names](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/tokenizers.html#Tokenizers-ClassicTokenizer) and do not split on them